# Pay with Amazon - Custom Integration - How to get PHP reference to response?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, amazon-pay

I am using the PHP SDK and the "OneTimePayments" PHP code from the sample application:
https://github.com/amzn/login-and-pay-with-amazon-sdk-samples/blob/master/PHP/SampleCartDemo/OneTimePayments/

In the code I'm using:

1. SetPaymentDetails.php executes Apicalls/GetDetails.php to setup the order.
2. ConfirmPaymentAndAuthorize.php executes Apicalls/ConfirmAndAuthorize.php to process the order.

In both GetDetails.php and ConfirmAndAuthorize.php there exists a PHP reference to the responses.

```
$response = $client->setOrderReferenceDetails($requestParameters);
$response = $client->confirmOrderReference($requestParameters);
```

However, I would like to have a PHP reference to the responses in both SetPaymentDetails.php and ConfirmPaymentAndAuthorize.php.

In each case, GetDetails.php and ConfirmAndAuthorize.php complete with an echo of the response in JSON, and these responses are displayed by the calling PHP file (SetPaymentDetails.php or ConfirmPaymentAndAuthorize.php) using:

```
<pre id="get_details_response"><div class="text-center"><img src="/images/ajax-loader.gif" /></div></pre>
<pre id="confirm"><code class="json"></code></pre>
<pre id="authorize"><div class="text-center"></div></pre>
```

where "get_details_response", "confirm" and "authorize" seem to be references to the responses.

But, I can't seem to use those references within the PHP code.

Can anyone tell me how I can get a PHP reference to these JSON responses within the SetPaymentDetails.php and ConfirmPaymentAndAuthorize.php files?

Thank you.

Comment: Not a Php person so perhaps I'm just misunderstanding. In both cases `$response` seems to be what you are looking for. The sample code ["serializes" it](https://github.com/amzn/login-and-pay-with-amazon-sdk-samples/blob/master/PHP/SampleCartDemo/OneTimePayments/Apicalls/GetDetails.php#L47) for output/display (re: to "human readable/pretty printed/formatted JSON string") in front end. Hth.

Comment: Hi EdSF.  Thanks for your "response".  Your statements about the functionality are accurate.  Looks like I may not have been clear; I'm wanting a PHP reference, like $response, in what you referred to as the front end files.  Am needing to process the response to obtain/use the values contained within.